# Check whether SelectBox has items, Robot-Framework, Selenium2Library

Tags: selenium-webdriver, robotframework

How can I check whether a `<select>` box has more than 1 `<option>`?

The `<option>`s are loaded using ajax and are placed into two `<optgroup>`s.

```
<option value="">default</option>
<optgroup ...>
    <option value=..>...
    <option ..>...
    ...
</optgroup>
<optgroup ...>
    <option ..>...
    <option ..>...
    ...
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `Get List Items` which will return a list of all items and then use `Get Length` to get the number of elements in the list:

```
Select Options Test
    Open Browser      your_url            chrome
    @{items}          Get List Items      id=select_list_id
    ${list_length}    Get Length          ${items}
    Should Be True    ${list_length} > 1
```

Comment: I like this answer for the simplicity!

Answer (score 1):

You have at least a couple of choices:

1. use the [Get Matching Xpath Count](http://rtomac.github.io/robotframework-selenium2library/doc/Selenium2Library.html#Get%20Matching%20Xpath%20Count) keyword to return the number elements that match an xpath which represents the options, or
2. Use [Get List Items](http://rtomac.github.io/robotframework-selenium2library/doc/Selenium2Library.html#Get%20List%20Items) to fetch all of the items, then use Get Length to return the length.

Since I can't write an example against your exact code, the following example runs against the page at http://the-internet.herokuapp.com/dropdown. It has markup that includes this (at the time I write this answer):

```
<select id='dropdown'>
    <option value="" disabled="disabled" selected="selected">Please select an option</option>
    <option value="1">Option 1</option>
    <option value="2">Option 2</option>
</select>
```

Here is a complete working example:

```
*** Test Cases ***
| Example 
| | 
| | Go to | ${ROOT}/dropdown
| | 
| | ${count}= | Get matching xpath count | //select[@id='dropdown']/option
| | Should be equal as numbers | ${count} | 3
| | 
| | @{items}= | Get list items | //select[@id='dropdown']
| | ${item count}= | Get Length | ${items}
| | Should be equal as numbers | ${item count} | 3

*** Settings ***
| Library        | Selenium2Library
| Suite Setup    | Open browser | ${ROOT} | ${BROWSER}
| Suite Teardown | Close all browsers

*** Variables ***
| ${BROWSER} | chrome
| ${ROOT}    | http://the-internet.herokuapp.com
```

Comment: Thanks for this answer with an alternative (after you edited it `:)`), which is highly useful as well. Have some kudos for your time! `:)`.